# Why am I consuming so much CPU and none of the GPU?

Tags: gpu, cpu, nvidia, houdini

I am working with Houdini (a 3d software) on a computer with an Intel Core i5-8400 2.80GHz and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB.

My issue is that Houdini is consuming all my CPU but nearly none of my GPU. It also happens when I run other programs like Blender, Unity or any other 3D software.

I've tryed installing the NVIDIA studio-ready drivers, with similar results. I'm sure that using a 3D software, I should be able to speed up the process with my GPU, but I can´t get it working.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to "enable" my GPU, please?

Here is a screenshot of my task manager running a stressful task in Houdini:
[image: Task manager]

Comment: Is there a specific function of Houdini you're trying to use that you know is supposed to utilize the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only specific parts of 3D app actually use the GPU.  The most obvious part is the 3D viewports but other parts might be optimized to utilize the GPU for simulation and rendering etc.  However 90%+ of Houdini/Maya/3DS Max etc still just uses CPU and most of that is still single threaded so you wont even have full CPU usage.